# Diagonalizability of matrix over C and R respectively

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I am new to linear algebra, and was asked the following question:

$A$ is a matrix of order n x n, $n \geq 2$, with characteristic polynomial $p(λ)=λ^n-1$. Is $A$ diagonalizable over **R**? over **C**?
If $A$ is diagonalizable then draw a diagonal matrix similar to A.

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $p(λ)=λ^n-1=0$, in other words $λ^n=1$

Over **C**:
$λ^n=1$ will have n solutions, so there will be n eigenvalues, with algebraic multiplicity 1.

$1 \leq$ geometric multiplicity $\leq $ algebraic multiplicity

so the geometric multiplicity is 1.
Geometric multiplicity = algebraic multiplicity, so $A$ is diagonalizable.

Over **R**:
$λ^n=1$ has a different number of solutions depending whether n is odd or even.

For example $λ^2=1$ gives λ=1, λ=-1; while $λ^3=1$ gives λ=1. Therefore we cannot check the geometric multiplicity, and we cannot know if A is diagonalizable.

I am lost as to the last part of the question, i.e. how to draw a diagonal matrix similar to A, over **C**. Any suggestions would be great!

Thank you!

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ then all the complex eigenvalues must be real...

Comment: You should also search the site before posting for similar questions. This can be helpful, e.g., see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761190/matrix-that-satisfies-polynomial-xn-1-is-diagonalizable).

Answer (score 1):

A similar matrix to $A$ over $\mathbb  C$ is

$$\bar{A} = \mbox{diag}(1, e^{2i \pi /n}, \dots , e^{2i (n-1) \pi/n})$$ as the $n$ roots of $p_n(\lambda) = \lambda^n-1$ are $1, e^{2i \pi /n}, \dots , e^{2i (n-1) \pi/n}$.

Comment: Thank you! and the rest of the answer is correct?

Comment: The rest seems indeed correct.